# Angular material input number spinner scrolling problem

Tags: html

In Chrome, when the mouse is in the input number field in Material, I can scroll the value with my mouse.

I uploaded the code to stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bpj321, and I found in Chrome I cannot scroll when the mouse is in the field, but in Firefox, I can scroll.

I do not want to scroll, so how can I prevent this?

Comment: Nothing to do with Angular or Material. That's just how Firefox and Chrome handle scroll on `<input type="number">`

Comment: Thank you, you are right. How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could disable the scrolling event on the input manually:

Find the input element:

```
const input = document.getElementById("your-input");
```

And disable the `wheel` default functionality:

```
    input.addEventListener("wheel", function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
    });
```

Answer (score 4):

I've added these lines in my app.component.ts

```
@HostListener('mousewheel', ['$event']) onMouseWheelChrome(event: any) {
    this.disableScroll(event);
}

@HostListener('DOMMouseScroll', ['$event']) onMouseWheelFirefox(event: any) {
    this.disableScroll(event);
}

@HostListener('onmousewheel', ['$event']) onMouseWheelIE(event: any) {
    this.disableScroll(event);
}


disableScroll(event: any) {
    if (event.srcElement.type === "number")
        event.preventDefault();
}
```

It works.

Answer (score 1):

You could also just disable from html by intercepting the wheel event and preventing it's default behavior:

```
<input type="number" (wheel)="$event.preventDefault()">
```